# Problems with bootstrap columns when a form is on the same line as other content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want my table to be on the right of my form, but it is not far away enough. Currently, my section looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
.form-box
  %h3 Restrictions
  %legend Restricted Locations
  .row
    .col-sm-6
      = form_for [:admin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
        %fieldset.inputs
          .control-group
            = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
            .controls
              = f.select :product, Restriction.all, prompt: 'US State'
        %fieldset
          %ol
            %li.button
              = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
    .col-sm-6
      %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
        %th State
        %th Remove
```

How do I get my form to not violate the boundaries of the `form-box` (just standard CSS)? Why is my table so close to my inline form?

**UPDATE**

After wrapping the rows in container, it looks like this:
[image]

But I want `US States` to be left aligned. How do I do this? My code:

```
.form-box
      %h3 Restrictions
      %legend
        Restricted Locations
      .container
        .row
          .col-sm-4
            = form_for [:blueadmin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
              %fieldset.inputs
                .control-group
                  = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
                  .controls
                    = f.select :product, Restriction.all, prompt: 'US State'
              %fieldset
                %ol
                  %li.button
                    = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
          .col-sm-6
            %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
              %th State
              %th Remove
```

Comment: The `.col-*` must be inside a `.row`

Comment: edited @ZimSystem

Comment: row needs to be inside a container,  set `.form_box` to be `.form_box.container`